# Forensic tools for disk and image analysis

Tags: disk

Are there any forensic tools or programs like FTK and EnCase in Windows for Linux?
Or any disk and image analysis tools?

Comment: I know that KALI LINUX has a ton of forensic tools preinstalled. You can either download that distribution (and run in live forensic mode=no unwanted changes to hdd etc. at all) or google what tools they use. I know this is not a real answer, but a hint for you to find something yourself.

Answer (score 0):

take a look to [DEFT](http://www.deftlinux.net/) Distribution Based ON Ubuntu

> DEFT (acronym for Digital Evidence & Forensics Toolkit) is a distribution made for Computer Forensics, with the purpose of running live on systems without tampering or corrupting devices (hard disks, pendrives, etc…) connected to the PC where the boot process takes place.
>
> The DEFT system is based on GNU Linux, it can run live (via DVDROM or USB pendrive), installed or run as a Virtual Appliance on VMware or Virtualbox. DEFT employs LXDE as desktop environment and WINE for executing Windows tools under Linux. It features a comfortable mount manager for device management.
>
> DEFT is paired with DART (acronym for Digital Advanced Response Toolkit), a Forensics System which can be run on Windows and contains the best tools for Forensics and Incident Response. DART features a GUI with logging and integrity check for the instruments here contained.
>
> Besides all this, the DEFT staff is devoted to implementing and developing applications which are released to Law Enforcement Officers, such as Autopsy 3 for Linux`